# Editing polygon points with LiveCode

Tags: ide, polygon, livecode

Using LiveCode, can I visually edit the points of a polygon and can I add and delete individual points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Right-click on the polygon graphic and select Reshape Polygon from the contextual menu or when it's selected choose Reshape Polygon from the object menu. Each point then gets a handle. You can create new points by option clicking and dragging a point.

Comment: Excellent - that makes things a lot easier :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to edit the points visually, you can also use the fact that a polygon is defined by a cr-separated list of (x,y) points. You can edit the list by script or put the points of graphic x into a field, edit the list, then set the points of the polygon.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this in script by changing the 'editmode' property of the graphic

```
set the editmode of graphic 1 to "polygon"
```

To remove the edit handles simple set the editmode back to empty:

```
set the editmode of graphic 1 to empty
```